# Programmatic log4j2 configuration not working

Tags: logging, configuration, log4j2

I'm trying to configure log4j2 programmatically, in a similar way to the docs (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html):

```
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setStatusLevel(Level.TRACE);
builder.setConfigurationName("Config");
AppenderComponentBuilder console = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "Console")
        .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT)
        .add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", logFormat));
builder.add(console);
builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
Configurator.initialize(builder.build());

LogManager.getLogger("foo.bar").debug("TestMsg");
```

However, the log message at the end is not logging anything to the console. Changing it to `error` does log something. I can't work out what is wrong from the trace logs. What have I missed, why is it not debug logging?

EDIT:

setting `follow: true` on the `ConsoleAppender` (we're changing stdout in the situation this is running) and adding this to the end makes it log things:

```
Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

However, it is not using our specified log format, it is using the simple conversion pattern - not even the default format! Is there some logger logging I can turn on to work out why it is doing this - the status trace logging is only on startup & shutdown?

Comment: I just tried your exact example and I can see the Log4j2 status logger output as well as the application test message on the console. Is the above *all* your program does? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're only seeing output when logging at ERROR level it suggests that the default configuration is active, not the configuration you specified in the above program. No idea how that could happen with the above program.

Comment: Does `Configurator.initialize` replace all the existing static config? Do you need to do something with the returned `LoggerContext` object?

Comment: Existing static configuration may not be affected by the programmatic configuration above (so it may remain as previously configured: the default error-to-console-only configuration). Not sure. I didn't do anything with the returned LoggerContext, I followed your code exactly. But my test program *only* has the code you showed. No static initialization or anything. Can you make the configuration the first thing you do, before other static initialization?

Comment: Ah, thats it - looks like there cannot be any log initialization (including `LogManager.getLogger`) before the reconfiguration, else it gets confused